# The remote server returned an error: NotFound. Silverlight + WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I'm trying to call web service for few hours.
I have added clientaccesspolicy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

and crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction,Content-Type"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

to root directory of my web site.
Web service is called from IIS, and it's working here.

But when I'm trying to call my wcf web service from silverlight application I get this error:

The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

This is log from Fiddler:

> a:InternalServiceFaultThe server was unable to process the request due to
>   an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn
>   on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from
>   ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug>
>   configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception
>   information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server
>   trace logs.

This is code, when I get an error:

```
public int EndUserExist(System.IAsyncResult result) {
       object[] _args = new object[0];
       int _result = ((int)(base.EndInvoke("UserExist", _args, result))); //Here
       return _result;
            }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Verify your end point is configured correctly. If you use proxy clases built by Visual Studio based on wsdl, you can also check if it's defined correctly (especially, if it contains UserExist method with appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right ;)
Now it's working.
I turned on debug in web.config so I got exception message in Fiddler.
I need to set identity user in pool on IIS for sql database.

Answer (score 9):

Look in your web.config for this text:  IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults
set that to true.  Then run your service request again and watch Fiddler this time it will tell you what you need to know.
May be anything from a SQL error to a null reference.  :-)

Comment: What's more. I create simply project, with sql connection. I put this connection string to this sqlConn and it is opening without any troubles...

Answer (score 0):

In your mobile device, go to wifi settings and edit current wifi connection.
Set proxy "Automatically detect settings".