# Fault Exception when using linq on sql db server data

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Hello I am using the method GetUserId

```
public static int? GetUserId(string providerId)
{
    using (var oAuthDb = new   AuthDBEntities())
    {
        bool userFound = oAuthDb.webpages_OAuthMembership.Any(
                             u => u.ProviderUserId == providerUserId);

        if (userFound)
        {
            webpages_OAuthMembership oAuthUser = 
                oAuthDb.webpages_OAuthMembership.First(
                    u => u.ProviderUserId == providerId);
            return oAuthUser.UserId;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the line of userFound is not ending and I got FaultException because of the time limit.

The Exception is:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
  Source=System.ServiceModel
  StackTrace:
       at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
       at CarManagerPhoneApp.CarManagerService.CarManagerApiClient.CarManagerApiClientChannel.EndUserIdByProviderId(IAsyncResult result)
       at CarManagerPhoneApp.CarManagerService.CarManagerApiClient.CarManagerPhoneApp.CarManagerService.ICarManagerApi.EndUserIdByProviderId(IAsyncResult result)
       at CarManagerPhoneApp.CarManagerService.CarManagerApiClient.OnEndUserIdByProviderId(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
       Source=System.Windows
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
            at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
       InnerException: System.Net.WebException
            HResult=-2146233079
            Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
            Source=System.Windows
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                 at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
                 at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
            InnerException:
```

In webpages_OAuthMembership there is only one line.

In app.config:

```
<add name="AuthDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AuthDb.csdl|res://*/AuthDb.ssdl|res://*/AuthDb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=***azureServerAddress***;initial catalog=AuthDB;persist security info=True;user id=***UserName***;password=***Password**;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I removed the info with stars (***) but it is correct in the original line

I think that the problem is with the providerName.

Can anyone help?

Comment: how many records in `webpages_OAuthMembership`??
please add the exception .ToString()

Comment: Look at the inner exception type: `System.Net.WebException`.  This is not a database error, some how you are making an HTTP request that is failing.  I'm guessing you have some OData data source set up maybe?

Comment: Can you explain?

I have wcf service named CarManagerApi that have method called UserIdByProviderId that call GetUserId method.

And I have sql db on azure that have webpages_OAuthMembership table.
For now there is only one member in this table.

I can't understand why it makes an exception

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9335914/3191896
if you'd like, let's troubleshoot together in this chatroom: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58059/chat-with-arie

Comment: Arie and i took the troubleshooting to a chatroom,

Solution was to change the password in the `ConnectionString` in `web.config`